# Warning Notification Updates

Tags: apt, laptop

since two days ago, there's some warning icon appear on my top bar like this

I've try click `Show Updates` but said my system already updated (last action bout two days ago too)

[image]

This is my apt lists

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

# MariaDB 10.0 repository list - created 2015-07-10 22:04 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
deb http://mariadb.biz.net.id//repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

```

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Can you please run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal and post the error message.

Comment: Now its disappear, i dont know for sure whats going on .. so its resolved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its normal again, but i'm not sure what made it disappear, this is what i did

- run `sudo apt-get update` -> until this step, warning still shown
- restart my laptop -> until this step, warning still shown

And after about one hour, warning disappear, so i think its solved for right now.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the symbol (sometimes triangle shape and red color dash,AFAIK) it will show the exact error message.The reason is dependency issue,

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Yes, before that warning appear, i've already did from update manager :)

Comment: =)..I faced similar one in Ubuntu...I did `update` after it solved @FerriSutanto